# php arrays - values that disappear

Tags: php, arrays, nodes

I tried to find an answer in the original docs of php.net, but I can't found a valid explanation to me. Could you help me in understanding why the node with value 4 disappears in the following code?
Thanks in advance,

```
$ARRAY = [
            "1" =>
                [
                    1, 2, 3
                ],
            4,
            "2" => [
                "2.1" => [ 5, 6, 7 ]
            ]
        ];

echo "ARRAY : <pre>".print_r( $ARRAY, 1 )."</pre><br/>";
```

Comment: `4` is at index location `1` and you already have that key with an array as value. Hence, this behavior. That being said, numeric keys aren't a good idea for associative arrays due to such issues.

Comment: `4` gets overwritten by `2` key.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the documentation string keys containing valid decimal ints will be cast to int type. This means that `"1"` and `"2"` will be casted to `1` and `2` accordingly.

Value `4` comes without a key so PHP will assign it the next integer after the largest key so far (which is 1) so value "4" will be assigned the key `2`.

Again as stated in the documentation if you assign multiple values to the same key PHP will keep only the latest value. Now you have two assignments to for key `2` so only the last one will be kept:

```
1 => [1, 2, 3],
2 => 4, // <- This will be ignored
2 => ["2.1" => [ 5, 6, 7 ]]
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP casts purely integer string keys to integer type, so `"1"` is not different from `1`:

```
var_export(['1' => 'Example']);
```

```
array (
  1 => 'Example',
)
```

PHP also completes missing keys in sequence:

```
var_export([25 => 'Example', 'No key here']);
```

```
array (
  25 => 'Example',
  26 => 'No key here',
)
```

PHP also allows to have duplicate keys, and the last value overwrites previous ones:

```
var_export([25 => 'Example', 25 => 'Final value']);
```

```
array (
  25 => 'Final value',
)
```

Taking this into account, it's easy to grasp what's going on: you're inadvertently overwriting key `2`.

Comment: Thank you guys, for all your responses!
It's clear now: I expected a more rigorous management, honestly.

Comment: Most rules make sense for a loosely typed language, but the "allow duplicate keys in an array literal" one makes you wonder what the original developer was thinking.